# az cli command to create service principal doesn't create certificate in keyvault

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-cli, azure-service-principal

I'm running the below lines of my script:

```
Write-Host "Creating KeyVault..."

az keyvault create --name mykeyvault --resource-group myrg --location polandcentral

Write-Host "Creating service principal..."

az ad sp create-for-rbac --name mysp --role contributor --scopes "/subscriptions/subscriptionid/resourceGroups/myrg" --create-cert --cert mycert --keyvault mykeyvault
```

But the effect is that a Keyvault is created as well as service principal. However those last three options of `az ad sp create-for-rbac` command doesn't seem to do anything, because:

1. When I browse my Keyvault in the portal, I can see it's empty
2. The output from the sp creation command is (and I would expect something different, since I'm making it use certificate created in KV):

   {
   "appId": "...",
   "displayName": "mysp",
   "password": "...",
   "tenant": "..."
   }

What is it that I'm doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

The `az ad sp create-for-rbac` command returns this output:

```
Found an existing application instance: (id) <here goes the guid>. We will patch it.
Creating 'contributor' role assignment under scope '/subscriptions/<sub_guid>'
  Role assignment already exists.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that, the certificates created in key vault via CLI is **only visible** to the user who created it by signing in via `az login`.

In my case, I connected to Azure via CLI using below command by signing in with **`Sri`** user:

```
az login --only-show-errors
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I ran your code in my environment, **certificate** created successfully in key vault along with service principal as below:

```
Write-Host "Creating KeyVault..."
az keyvault create --name srikeyvault06 --resource-group Sri --location polandcentral

Write-Host "Creating service principal..."
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name srisp06 --role contributor --scopes "/subscriptions/subId/resourceGroups/Sri" --create-cert --cert mycert06 --keyvault srikeyvault06
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, you can also run below CLI command that retrieves certificates present in specific key vault:

```
az keyvault certificate list --vault-name srikeyvault06
```

**Response:**

[image]

> You cannot see that certificate if you are trying to access the key vault from **different** user account and missed adding key vault access policy with `List` permission to that user.

When I tried to check the same from **different** user account, I got below screen with no certificates:

[image]

To **resolve** this, you need to add new access policy in key vault by enabling `List` access for certificates to other user too like this:

[image]

When I tried to check the same from that user account again, I can find the **certificate** successfully in key vault as below:

[image]

Comment: I'm creating everything from the scope of the user I'm logged in as. But I can see that on the video you attached your output is slightly different than mine - in your case the password property is empty but in mine - I get a string in there. It's like my cert-related options have been ignored...

Comment: Are you able to create the certificate in key vault manually via Portal with same user?

Comment: Yes, I can. However, I had to add some random subject, but that's probably irrelevant :)

Comment: Any specific error it is throwing while running the script? What RBAC and directory roles you currently have?

Comment: Nope, no errors, however I'm getting a message from the az ad sp create-for-rbac (take a look at the edited quesion) - maybe that's the differentiating factor?

Comment: That message will be displayed if there is an existing application with that name and that won't be an issue. Could you check key vault access configuration and confirm with what access it is created? Rbac or vault access policy?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255875/discussion-between-sridevi-and-marek-m).

Comment: Although this answer didn't directly help me in fixing my problem, you've put me on the right track, so I'm accepting it, thanks!